# Extension of transcendental element

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $K$ be a field, and let $K\subset E\subset K(a)$ be an extension, where $a$ is transcendental element over $K$. How can I show that $K(a)/E$ is finite ?

Comment: similar to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1095336/x-is-algebraic-over-e

Comment: That's just false: take $E=K$.

Comment: $\subset$ must mean proper containment here

Comment: In short, consider some $f\in K(a)\setminus K$, and show that $[K(a):K(f)]$ is finite.

Comment: Yes, $\subset$ mean proper containment

Comment: Oh. Well, then this is the exact same question as Krish's link, since a field extension is finite iff it's algebraic and finitely generated.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot about this property.